# JSlint error in vim while defining functions using fat arrow (fart) syntax

Tags: debugging, vim, ecmascript-6, jslint, arrow-functions

Recently i developed the habit of defining functions as

```
()=>{

}
```

but `jslint` in vim with `syntastic` shows error with the same and wants the definition in format of

```
function(){

}
```

Am i missing something ? Is the first definition somehow incorrect and should not be used or some additional parameters passed in jslint ?

Comment: Don't put too much stock in the *opinions* of a tool like jsLint. More important to understand the differences between different syntaxes and use them in the best way you know how.

Comment: @squint the main issue is i kind of need to suppress the warnings somehow. syntastic takes up a lot of my screen size with errors and i have a huge codebase where i used the first method. Can't change to second everywhere...

Comment: Maybe use a better, more configurable linter, like ESLint.

Answer (score 2):

JSLint intends arrow functions to be used for one-line expressions:

```
let es7 = () => Object.hasOwnProperty("getOwnPropertyDescriptors");
es7();
```

Since it also discourages the use of `this` inside of the body of a function, and arrow functions cannot be named.

> Fat arrow parameters can be visually confused with expressions. Fat arrow functions cannot reasonably return object literals.
>
> The rational for farts was that they are better for writing simple functions that only return the result of executing a simple expression.
>
> Farts went wrong in changing the meaning of 'this' and 'arguments', but JSLint discourages the use of 'this' and 'arguments', so it doesn't matter.

In addition, the curly braces can be ambiguous:

> If you are creating a simple factory function, you cannot put an object literal on the right of the `=>` because a brace will be interpreted as a function body. So instead you must use:

```
  let bar = () => ({}); // wrap the object literal in parens
```

> Fortunately, JSLint will be able detect these sorts of ambiguities.

In addition, arrow functions defined in the global scope, as values of object literals, or as methods of function prototypes use the top level host object (`window` or `global`) as the context, rather than the parent function as in other cases.

**References**

- [What is the meaning of this? | YUI Blog](https://yuiblog.com/blog/2012/03/30/what-is-the-meaning-of-this/)
- [ES6 fat arrow functions, aka farts](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/TxQ4gRkZxST)
- [Constant confusion: why I still use JavaScript function statements](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/constant-confusion-why-i-still-use-javascript-function-statements-984ece0b72fd)
- [An Introduction to JavaScript ES6 Arrow Functions - StrongLoop](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/an-introduction-to-javascript-es6-arrow-functions/)
- [When 'not' to use arrow functions](https://rainsoft.io/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/)